# Running tesseract from terminal - Python 3.6.3

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, subprocess, tesseract, os.system

I'm attempting to run `tesseract tesseract_inputs/test.png stdout > textfile.txt` from the terminal, and either return it to `python`, or just have it leave the results in a text file. I can't figure out what I need to input into subprocess or system in order to achieve this.

`subprocess.run('tesseract tesseract_inputs/test.png stdout > textfile.txt')`

or

`os.system('tesseract tesseract_inputs/test.png stdout > textfile.txt')`